# Automatically recognize dates in Safari to add in calendar

Tags: safari

In Mail, when you point on a an appointment-like text (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) Mail shows you a button to add it as an event in Calendar. Is there something like this in Safari or an extension to allow this?